# Table Empty when adding content

Tags: lua, lua-table, crysis

I'm having a huge problem when I've added content to a table (Lua), where all content in the table suddenly disappears. 
The table in question holds the data for a banlist (608 entries at present) and is placed within the table by using *table.insert*, however the lead entry for the user is done as *Umbra.Banlist[profileId] = {};*. The *Umbra.Banlist[profileId] = {};* table alone should mean that there's content within the Umbra.Banlist table.
I get no errors when running the code, and when using

```
    if (#Umbra.Banlist == 0) then
        System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." The Banlist seems to be empty. It seems that some part of loading has failed.");
    end
```

I get this:

[image: 1]

I've looked on the web and on this site but there doesn't seem to be any related questions, so I'm posting it here.

This code is part of a server mod for Crysis Wars (see the whole function below), but has the entire Lua library at hand (so don't worry if you don't think your answer won't solve the problem).

*The Code:*

```
    Umbra.ReadBans = function()
    self = Umbra;
    System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." Starting banlist read.");
    FileHnd, err = io.open(Root().."Mods/Infinity/System/Read/Banlst.lua", "r");
    if (not FileHnd) then
        System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." Unable to find file 'Banlst.lua'.");
        return;
    end
    for line in FileHnd:lines() do
        local name, profile, ip, domain, reason, date, bannedby = line:match([[Umbra.BanSystem:Add%('(.-)', '(.+)', '(.+)', '(.+)', '(.+)', '(.+)', '(.-)'%);]]);
        if (not name) then
            System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." Failed to read the banlist at line "..count or 0);
            break;
        end
        System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." Banlist; Name: [ "..name.." ], For: [ "..reason.." ], By: [ "..bannedby.." ]");
        --local Msg, Date, Reason, Type, Domain = line:match([[User:Read%( "(.-)", { Date="(.+)"; Reason="(.+)"; Typ="(.+)"; Info="(.+)"; } %);]]);
        --User:Read( "Banned", { Date="31.03.2011"; Reason="WEBSTREAM"; Typ="Inetnum"; Info="COMPUTER.SED.gg"; } );
        --Umbra.BanSystem:Add('patryk', '258132298', '178.183.243.163', '178.183.243.163.dsl.dynamic.t-mobile.pl', 'flyhack', '08/11/2012 | 21:39:53', 'Anti-Noob');
        Umbra.Banlist[profile] = {};
        table.insert(Umbra.Banlist[profile], name);
        table.insert(Umbra.Banlist[profile], ip);
        table.insert(Umbra.Banlist[profile], domain);
        table.insert(Umbra.Banlist[profile], reason);
        table.insert(Umbra.Banlist[profile], date);
        table.insert(Umbra.Banlist[profile], bannedby);
        --[[Umbra.Banlist[profile].name = name;
        Umbra.Banlist[profile].ip = ip;
        Umbra.Banlist[profile].domain = domain;
        Umbra.Banlist[profile].reason = reason;
        Umbra.Banlist[profile].date = date;
        Umbra.Banlist[profile].bannedby = bannedby;--]]
        if not count then count = 0; end
        count = count + 1;
    end
    Umbra.Bans = {};
    Umbra.Bans.cnt = count;
    System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." Read "..count.." banned players (added into the Umbra Global Banlist)");
    if (#Umbra.Banlist == 0) then
        System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." The Banlist seems to be empty. It seems that some part of loading has failed.");
    end
    count = nil; --Purge this one as well, again!
end
```

***Edit:***

I don't get the message that the code below should print if their profile doesn't exist in the table, so their profile does actually exist.

```
    if (not Umbra.Banlist[profile]) then
            System.LogAlways(Umbra.Tag.." Error in 'Umbra.Banlist': The profile does not exist.)");
            break;
        end
```

**Another Edit:**

Proof that the system *can* in fact get the 'ID' variable:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I do apologise for some of the names visible in the screenshot- I can't help this and I'm not editing the banlist just for a screenshot on here.

Comment: You could edit the screenshot to redact the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to use this function to get count of items in table:

```
function count(t)
    local c=0;
    for i in pairs(t) do c=c+1; end
    return c;
end
--...
if(count(Umbra.Banlist)==0)then
    --...
end
```

The thing is, that # counts an array/table with number indexes, but you have table with string indexes. # is same like when you would replace "pairs" with "ipairs" in that count function. So and when you do #Umbra.Banlist, where all indexes are strings, it returns 0, because there are 0 integer indexes, but it does not mean, that table is empty.

Comment: Upon using a tostring() for the profile, I can access the table for the profile properly.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Near the end of your code you have `#Umbra.Banlist == 0` but I don't see any item insertions into it by numeric keys. Here are some things to check to see if you're assumptions matches up with reality.

Check that `profile` isn't `nil`. It looks like in your use-case you're assuming it's a number. You can check this easily with:

```
assert(profile)
assert(type(profile) == 'number')
```

If `profile` is actually not a number type then checking Umbra.Banlist with `#` operator is faulty. Note `#` does not count the associative part of the table. If you only care whether Umbra.Banlist is empty or not you can use `if next(Umbra.Banlist) then` to check for it.

Comment: Yes, Umbra.Banlist is a number (9 digit). Using the _if next(Umbra.Banlist)_ yields the same result. Perhaps I'm reading the file wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderStopher The captures are going to be in string form. Try `tonumber(profile)` to convert it into a number assuming profile is really that.

Comment: @AlexanderStopher to help debugging you can also log and print out `name, profile, ip, domain, etc...` to confirm it's capturing what you expect.

Comment: See the screenshot, this is what is happening in it.

Comment: @AlexanderStopher I don't see profile variable printed out anywhere in that screenshot.

Comment: Each line with the 'UMBRA CORE Banlist;' on it have the variables printed out. The Profile variable definitely works because when I execute the command for the banlist (reads directly from the file again), it has the profile (see the new image in the initial post).

Comment: @AlexanderStopher If you look at the system log line in your code, `profile` is never included in that Umbra CORE when you concat the string. In the second screenshot are those numbers actually prefixed with a `#` symbol when you read it into profile?

Comment: In the second screenshot, the numbers are not prefixed with '#' and are directly read into the command console (the thing you see with the contents of the tables).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34437/discussion-between-greatwolf-and-alexander-stopher)